# python : the longest word in a string

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm developing a function that returns the longest word from a string, my code is :

```
def longestWord(sen):
    max = 1
    i = 0
    ind = 1
    while ind != 0 :
        if sen[i] == " ":
            i = i+1
        word = ""
        lenth = 0

        while(sen[i] != " " and i < len(sen)):
            word = word + sen[i]
            lenth = lenth+1
            if(lenth > max):
                max = lenth
                longestword = word
            i = i+1
            if i == len(sen)-1:
                ind = 0



    return longestword

print(longestWord("ceci est un texte"))
```

When I try to run it an error shows up saying that "string index out of range"

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\tp2\longestWord.py", line 25, in <module>
        print(longestWord("ceci est un texte"))
      File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\tp2\longestWord.py", line 11, in longestWord
        while(sen[i] != " " and i < len(sen)):
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Is your question what "string index out of range" means?

Comment: what is your expected output for the string `"ceci est un texte"`

Comment: because the code is unpythonic. For starters try swap ```sen[i] != " "``` and ```i < len(sen)```

Comment: You need to check length *first*, `while i < len(sen) and sen[i] != " ":` Otherwise you try to access `sen[i]` before you confirm `i` is a legal index for `sen`.

Comment: Please be mindful of the indentation of your code. Just adding four spaces before your first line isn't enough to correctly format your code. Please read [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: it works when I put the condition about lenth first. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a very complicated way. A simple pythonic way would be:

```
def longest_word(s):
    return max(s.split(), key=len)
```

Output:

```
>>> longest_word("ceci est un texte")
"texte"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line

```py
def longest_word(sentence): 
    return sorted(sencente.split(), key = lambda x: len(x))[-1]

print(longest_word("ceci est un texte"))
```

Comment: Why not just use `max`?

Comment: You are right max is better

Comment: You could also use the `reverse` argument to `sorted` and grab the first element. `sorted(sencente.split(), key = lambda x: len(x), reverse = True)[0]`

Comment: true but `[-1]` is shorter than `reverse = True`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the results in a list, because *multiple* words may be the same length.

```
def longest_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    maxlen = max(len(w) for w in words)
    return [w for w in words if len(w) == maxlen]
```

Or in one pass:

```
def longest_words(sentence):

    words = sentence.split()
    results = []
    maxlen = 0

    for w in words:

        curlen = len(w)

        if curlen > maxlen:
            results = [w]
            maxlen = curlen
        elif curlen == maxlen:
            results.append(w)

    return results
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace your function with this one :

```
def longestWord(string) :
    lettersCounter = 0
    result = ""
    for word in string.split() :
        if(len(word) > lettersCounter) :
            lettersCounter = len(word)
            result = word

    return result
```

print(longestWord("ceci est un texte"))